# Switch off JavaScript validation

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-webform, drupal-form-validation

I am using the Webform and the [Inline Form Errors](https://drupal.org/project/ife) module, and I want inline validation.

However, out the box, the Webform module seems to have some JavaScript validation and I would like to turn it off.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please post all drupal related questions on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Webform does not have any client-side validation out of the box. If I had to guess, you have an email field and are viewing the site with Firefox, Chrome or Opera. Those browsers try to automatically validate HTML5 email fields.